# React component NOT updating by itself after change in data without refreshing the entire page

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks

I am using ReactJS on the front-end to make a POST request to my Djando API. After I make the POST request, I expect for my React component to update itself without me having to refresh the entire page. I'm using a useEffect hook to call the my endpoint(GET) to retrieve the data I just updated.

```
import React from 'react'
import CampaignList from '../components/CampaignList'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'



const campaignRequest = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email_address: "zztop1111122233344556677889910101010@gmail.com",
      first_name: "i",
      last_name: "k",
      stage: "1"
    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}


let Campaigns = () => {
  
  const [recipients, setRecipients] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  console.log("Campaign is re-mounted")
  useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setRecipients(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      
      // fetchData()
  }
  ,[]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Campaigns</div>
      <CampaignList recipientss={recipients}/>
      {/* <div> 
        {recipients.map((recipient, index) => (
             <h3 key={index}>{recipient.email_address}
             </h3> 
            
          ))}
      </div> */}
      <button onClick={campaignRequest}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Campaigns
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you click the button nothing updates? I think it doesn't because campainRequest() makes a call to your api and gets the data, but doesn't actually put it in your recipients list, it just logs it.

Comment: I meant that when I click the button to use my POST request, the data gets posted to my backend, but my component(Campaign) that has a GET request gets that data, but my page only gets updated when I refresh the browser. I'm looking to make it work so that Component gets updated without me having to refresh that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have anything triggering that get fetch to get called again

put this in your onClick

```
() => {
 campaignRequest()
 setLoad(true);
 }
```

and this in ur useeffect

```
if (load) {
   ....
   setLoad(false);
 }
 }, [load])
```

Comment: That fetch is being called by a button in my return on the bottom. The data does show up when I refresh the page, so I'm assuming the right data is being passed through.

Comment: @ek1669 I updated the answer to show you. When you click it shows up in console i assume, yet the ui is not updated either because you are not making api calls properly in the useEffect right now.

Comment: In mycase I can't bring the setRecipients into my fetch POST request, because I only initiate that useState in my Campaign component

Comment: @ek1669 This is your issue, I just updated

Comment: @ek1669 You will also need that load state to be initialized to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Now recipients are updated every time you click.

```
import React from "react";
import CampaignList from "../components/CampaignList";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let Campaigns = () => {
    const [recipients, setRecipients] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const campaignRequest = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email_address: "zztop1111122233344556677889910101010@gmail.com",
                first_name: "i",
                last_name: "k",
                stage: "1",
            }),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setRecipients(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };

    console.log("Campaign is re-mounted");
    useEffect(() => {
        campaignRequest();
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Campaigns</div>
            <CampaignList recipientss={recipients} />
            <button onClick={campaignRequest}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Campaigns;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no since the POST API get's triggered every time I click on my navigation that leads to the Campaign tab in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to `POST` some data to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/` when `Click Me` is clicked and then automatically `GET` data from the same URL when `POST` completes.

In your code snippet a `GET` request is located inside of a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependencies array, so it will be executed exactly once - on the initial rended.

If you want to keep the same code structure, you would have to introduce a new state variable that would trigger the `useEffect` hook - `isAddCampaignLoading` for example. You can then move `const campaignRequest = () => {...}` inside of the `Campaigns` component and change the `isAddCampaignLoading` state when `campaignRequest` succeeds. Finally, you will add `isAddCampaignLoading` to the dependencies array of your `useEffect` hook to make it execute every time `isAddCampaignLoading` changes. I also added a check inside of the hook to make sure campaigns are fetched only when `isAddCampaignLoading` is `false` (`campaignRequest` succeeds).

```
import React from 'react'
import CampaignList from '../components/CampaignList'
import {
    useState,
    useEffect
} from 'react'

let Campaigns = () => {
    const [recipients, setRecipients] = useState([]);
    const [isFetchCampaignsLoading, setIsFetchCampaignsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isAddCampaignLoading, setIsAddCampaignLoading] = useState(false);

    const campaignRequest = () => {
        setIsAddCampaignLoading(true)
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email_address: "zztop1111122233344556677889910101010@gmail.com",
                first_name: "i",
                last_name: "k",
                stage: "1"
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            .finally(() => setIsAddCampaignLoading(false))
    }

    console.log("Campaign is re-mounted")
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isAddCampaignLoading) {
            setIsFetchCampaignsLoading(true);
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaigns/')
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    setRecipients(data);
                    setIsAddCampaignLoading(false);
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
                .finally(() => setIsFetchCampaignsLoading(false))
        }
    }, [isAddCampaignLoading]);

    if (isFetchCampaignsLoading) {
        return <p> Loading... </p>;
    }

    return ( <div>
            <div> Campaigns </div> 
            <CampaignList recipients={recipients}/> 
            {
            /* <div> 
                        {recipients.map((recipient, index) => (
                             <h3 key={index}> 
                                {recipient.email_address}
                             </h3> 
                          ))}
                      </div> */
        } 
           <button onClick={campaignRequest}>Click Me</button> 
           </div>
    )
}

export default Campaigns
```

Comment: This is working for me, but it seems like my page is refreshing as a result. After I submit the Click Me button, the list is updated but then the page is refreshing to the top of my page.

Comment: @ek1669 you are probably seeing the page going white every time the campaigns are fetched because `isAddCampaignLoading` gets set to `true`, so `<p> Loading... </p>` is returned instead of the main `div`. You can consider either removing `if (isFetchCampaignsLoading) { return <p> Loading... </p>; }` altogether or putting it inside of the main `div`. You should also consider another field as key for your `<h3 key={index}>` since positional indexes should not be used as keys in React - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. This might cause issues with the way the list is updated.